# Open a new file in VS Code via URL with provided text content

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

VS Code can be opened via a link by using `vscode://file://<full path>`

Is there a way open a new file in VS Code with provided content?

I've [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/0m8hygu4/1/) with a data and blob URLs, but it only opens a new VS Code window

```js
const mystring = "Hello World!";
data.href += "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(mystring);
blob.href += URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([mystring], {
    type: 'text/plain'
}))
```

```html
<a id="data" href="vscode://">Open VSCode via data</a>
<br>
<a id="blob" href="vscode://">Open VSCode via blob</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this, but it would require writing an extension, and the user having that extension installed. In the extension, choose some scheme name, define and implement a `TextDocumentContentProvider` for that scheme and implement `provideTextDocumentContent(uri: Uri, token: CancellationToken): ProviderResult<string>`, and register your provider. You can find an example in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/contentprovider-sample/src/provider.ts.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found that info by googling "`github vscode issues open url with untitled content`" and finding [Opening a new tab/untitled/unsaved file from text content #8975](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8975).

Note that if you were opening the text document manually in an extension instead of from user clicking a VS Code URL, then you could just use `openTextDocument` with its `content` option (see the `openTextDocument(options?: {content: string, language: string}): Thenable<TextDocument>` signature in [the API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)).