# How to put a custom title for virtual text document in VSCode Extension API?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am utilizing the `openTextDocument` function to open a virtual document and displaying it through `showTextDocument`. I aim to assign a custom window title to the virtual document, similar to the approach used in the [WebView API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview).

extension.ts

```js
...

vscode.workspace
  .openTextDocument({
    content
    language: document.languageId,
  })
  .then((doc) => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc, {
      viewColumn: vscode.ViewColumn.Beside, // Editor column to show the text document panel in.
      preserveFocus: true, // new text document panel will not take focus
    });
  });

...
```

I prefer not to utilize the WebView API. Could you please guide me on achieving this using the document API? Thank you.

Comment: see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99403, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102739, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77748321/11107541